# React Router 6 with i18next how to create multi language urls?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, internationalization, i18next

I have 2 languages, using i18n. I want to once the user changes the language, change the url, then inside a component access the chosen languages from the url. I cannot find anything on how to do it with react router 6 and all I found doesnt help. Any idea or help would be very much appreciated!!!!!

App.js

```
const baseUrl = () => (i18n.language === "de" ? "/" : "/" + i18n.language);

function App() {
    return (
        <Router basename={baseUrl()}>
            <div className="App">
                <Header />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route>
                        <Route path='terms' element={<Terms />} />
                          <Route path='privacy' element={<PrivacyPolicy />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Footer.js

```
const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/terms">{t('terms')}</Link>
            <Link to="/privacy">{t('privacy')}</Link>
            ...
        </div>
    )
};
export default Footer;
```

LanguageSwitch.js

```
const LanguageSwitch = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedLang, setSelectedLang] = useState(currentLanguage);

    const onChangeLang = (code, label) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(code);
        setSelectedLang({label, code});
        setOpen(!open)
    };
...
};
```